# Как сделать независимый скролл в блоке с абсолютным позиционированием?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Есть aside c position: absolute. В нём список ul>li*12. Как сделать этому блоку независимую прокрутку? overflowY: scroll, hidden и auto не помогают, элементы всё равно отображаются ниже границы aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может `overflow-y` вы неправильно используете?

```css
aside {
  position:absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

aside ul {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Точно, я не задал высоту aside. Спасибо!